# How to set deaful Authorization in .net core 2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using a custom requirement like this:

```
    services.AddAuthorization(options => {
        options.AddPolicy("MyAuthorizationRequirement",policy => {
            policy.Requirements.Add(new MyRequirement());
        });
    });
```

I want to be able to set an `[Authorize]` attribute on my controller and use a custom authorization method.

but with the custom requirement i set i have to use [Authrization("MyAuthorizationRequirement")]

how can I set some sort of default to use just a single attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to explain what is required here.

What `services.AddAuthorization` does is, it tries to configure authorization. Before configuring authorization first you need to configure authentication. For that in the `ConfigureServices` method, you can do something like this.

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options => 
    {
        options.Audience = "http://localhost:5001/";
        options.Authority = "http://localhost:5000/";
    });
```

Now you can configure,

```
services
    .AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("PolicyName", policy => policy.RequireClaim("SomeClaimName"));
        // you can configure your requirement above in various ways, you might want to check those out
    });
```

And finally on the `Configure` method,

```
app.UseAuthentication();
```

So now in the controller,

```
// [Authorize("PolicyName")]
// If you have above in your controllers/actions, those will only be accessible to users who has "SomeClaimName"

// [Authorize]
// Those who are authenticated, can access these endpoints
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new class which inherit from `AuthorizeAttribute`

```
public class MyAuthorizationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public MyAuthorizationAttribute()
        : base("MyAuthorizationRequirement")
    {
    }
}
```

and use `[MyAuthorization]` on your controllers.

Comment: This is how i started.. But then i got an error 

`No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.`

Comment: That's another problem, did you add any Authentication Service like cookie or JWTbearer?

Comment: No ... I need a cuatom authentication method .. So i need to add one and only the can i use the authorize attribute ?